# Jade Template Engine error when using a layout

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm making an application in which the sidebar navigation stays on all the pages. Instead of duplicating content, I want to make the navigation in the layout file and use it in other jade files.

Here's the layout.pug file:

```
html
head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')
    title= title
body
    #wrapper
        #sidebar-wrapper
            ul.sidebar-nav
                li.sidebar-brand
                    a(href="#") LMS
                li
                    a(href="#") Dashboard
                li
                    a(href="#") Search
                li
                    a(href="#") Issue
    block dashboard
```

and here's my index.pug file:

```
extends layout
block dashboard
    p Welcome to express
```

The router file is standard and renders the index file.
But when I try to load up the application in the browser I get this error.

```
GET / 500 241.336 ms - 1178
Error: C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\LMS\views\error.pug:3

Unexpected block content
at makeError (C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\LMS\node_modules\pug-error\index.js:32:13)
at error (C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\LMS\node_modules\pug-linker\index.js:7:30)
at C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\LMS\node_modules\pug-linker\index.js:47:9
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at link (C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\LMS\node_modules\pug-linker\index.js:45:20)
at compileBody (C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\LMS\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:171:9)
at Object.exports.compile (C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\LMS\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:243:16)
at handleTemplateCache (C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\LMS\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:216:25)
at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\LMS\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:428:10)
at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\LMS\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:418:21)
```

This error code is pretty ambiguous and I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

EDIT 1:
Here's error.pug

```
extends layout
block content
h1= message
h2= error.status
pre #{error.stack}
```

Comment: JADE is called PUG now..can you post your error.pug. I think the problem is there..on line 3

Comment: Error in `error.pug` file, please add this content to the question.

Comment: @ojf I used express to generate the basic files and directories, so error.pug was generated for me.

Comment: your route is throwing an error, and then the error page itself is throwing an error when trying to render. Change "block content" to "block dashboard" to see the error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here it is your route is throwing an error and then your error page is also throwing an error when attempting to render. Change error.pug line 2 to read

```
block dashboard
```

Instead of

```
block content
```

and the actual error will be revealed

Comment: So I made this change and another error regarding indentation came, fixed the indentation and now the navigation is appearing correctly. But it overlaps the content of the index.pug. It's related to css right? Because I want everything other than layout.pug to appear beside the navigation instead of below it. 
P.S: I copied a side bar nav template from the web.

Comment: Start a new question mate. :)